# mysql error 1442 trigger when inserting a new record from table A to table B and vice versa

Tags: mysql

I have these two triggers, which trigger A inserts from table A to table B, and vice-versa :

```
DELIMITER //    
CREATE TRIGGER insert_split
BEFORE INSERT ON user FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF new.level_id = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO petugas (nama_petugas, email, username, tgl_lahir, no_hp, created_by, updated_by, created_at, updated_at)
            VALUES (new.name, new.email, new.username, new.dob, new.phone, '1', '1', NOW(), NOW());
        ELSEIF new.level_id = '2' THEN
            INSERT INTO bidan (nama_bidan, email, username, tgl_lahir, no_hp, created_by, updated_by, created_at, updated_at)
            VALUES (new.name, new.email, new.username, new.dob, new.phone, '1', '1', NOW(), NOW());
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO ibu (nama_ibu, email, username, tgl_lahir, no_hp, created_by, updated_by, created_at, updated_at)
            VALUES (new.name, new.email, new.username, new.dob, new.phone, '1', '1', NOW(), NOW());
        END IF;
    END;
    DELIMITER ;
```

and this second trigger

```
DELIMITER //    
CREATE TRIGGER insert_user_ibu
BEFORE INSERT ON ibu FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT into user (name, username, email, password, dob, phone, level_id, is_active,created_at, updated_at) 
        VALUES (new.nama_ibu, new.email, new.email, md5('qwerty'), new.tgl_lahir, new.no_hp, '3', '1', NOW(), NOW());
    END; //
```

But after I create both trigger insert regardless before or after, I execute this :

```
insert into user(id, name, username, phone, dob, email, password, level_id, is_active, created_at, updated_at) values 
('30', 'Janice', 'janice123@yahoo.com', '087769958123', '2001-01-01', 'janice123@yahoo.com', md5('admin123'), '3', '1', NOW(), NOW());
```

or this

```
insert into ibu(id, nama_ibu, tempat_lahir, tgl_lahir, gol_dar, pendidikan, pekerjaan, alamat, city_id, province_id, no_hp, email, created_by, updated_by, created_at, updated_at) values 
('5', 'Jessica', '1201', '2000-01-01', 'O', 'Tidak Sekolah', 'Tidak Bekerja', 'Testing', '1201', '12', '081211223344', 'jessica123@gmail.com', '1', '1', NOW(), NOW());
```

it won't work, and show error :

```
1442 - Can't update table 'user' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

the trigger function means, I want to insert a record to table A, so in table B are inserted too, and vice-versa. But it shows error. Anybody have solution this? So, I can insert a record, from table A is inserted in table B too, and from table B is inserted in table A.

Comment: Your triggers are circular. That is, an insertion on `user` will trigger an insertion on `ibu`, which will trigger an insertion on `user` that triggers an insertion on `ibu`... Only insert on one table and let the trigger handle the insertion on the other. Never insert directly to the second table.  The real problem here is that your database design is flawed. You shouldn't be storing the same data in multiple tables.